# Can we add custom className prop to "Col" or "Row" components in react bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, padding, margin, react-bootstrap

I gave a className to my Row and Col component inside a container then why padding and margin property doesn't work in my custom class?

**my react code-**

```
<Container fluid id="about-title-container">
        <Row className="about-title-row-1">
        <Col className="about-title-row-1-col-1">
                <h1 className="about-title-h1">About Us</h1>
        </Col>
        </Row>
</Container>
```

**my CSS code-**

```
.about-title-row-1{
    padding: 4%;
    text-align: center;
}

.about-title-row-1-col-1{
    padding: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: works well if I use id as a prop instead of the className

Answer (score 0):

because `Row` component has default left and right margin of `-15px` and `Col` has default left and right margin of `15px`. To override this you can to use `!important` in your css :

```
.about-title-row-1{
    padding: 4% !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.about-title-row-1-col-1{
    padding: 2% !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

or use `noGutters` prop on Row component to remove margin and padding like this :

```
<Row noGutters></Row>
```

also you can use bootstrap classes for padding and margin.